# Nhibernate and max(uniqueID) as one of three criteria?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a database table with lots of columns, a primary key(icd_data_id), and a foreign key(encounter_id).

I have a particular criteria which should only appear once, but because of past history, I cannot be sure that there is only one record which fits the criteria, therefore, I am trying to get the last value.

I don't know how to solve this with my mapping file and queries.  Here's a subset of what would be in my class in the mapping file.

```
 <class name="Surgery">
<id name="ID" column="icd_data_id" type="Int32">
  <generator class="identity"/>
</id>

<property name="EncounterID" column="event_id" type="int" />
<property name="SpongeCountDone" column="sponge_removed" type="AnsiString" />

<more attributes here, excluded for brevity>

<property name="Category" column="category" type="AnsiString" />
</class>
```

What I want to get is the row with the max(icd_data_id) where Category = 'XYZ' and EncounterID = 123.

The Category value I'm looking for will always be static, but the EncounterID will 
be the value that I will have in code when going to get data from this table.

If I wasn't clear, there are other records for this encounterID in the table where the Category isn't XYZ, and there should be only one where Category = XYZ for each encounter, but it is possible that there will be more than one.

Does anyone here have any experience with how to write the three criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in Notepad, but it can look like this:

`var results = session.CreateQuery("from Surgery p where Category='XYZ' and EncounterID=123 and p.icd_data_id in (
    select max(p2.icd_data_id) from Surgery p2 
    group by p2.icd_data_id)")`